# Как настроить Lavalink сервер на Github для Discord бота?

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord.py

Хочу сделать музыкального бота на discord.py. Код уже готов и работает с компьютера, но никак не могу найти информацию по тому, как сделать так, чтобы Lavalink работал на Github. Для этого мне нужно запускать Lavalink сервер и подключаться к нему. C компа запускал сервер через командную строку (`java -jar Lavalink.jar`), однако не смог залить этот .jar файл на гитхаб из-за слишком большого размера. Можно ли как-то залить этот файл или есть какой-то другой способ это сделать? Вот ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/Nockech/8921 (бота хосчу через Heroku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подробно и поэтапно написано в документации Heroku по развертыванию Java/Python app : [java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java) или [python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python)

Github не является сервером, это всего лишь хранилище. На Heroku вам надо загрузить исходный код и скомпилировать там, там же и запускаете.